# Rails ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError 'true' on _destroy of child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a strange bug. I'm trying to hunt down the reason for things to break all of a sudden.

It has to do with the `_destroy` method on a child model when set true it raises an `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError` where for some reason the `true` value has made itself into a parameter key instead of a value.

I understand this is what is causing the error, but not a clue as to why.

Below is the params hash that is getting posted that raises the error. It is the _destroy=true for the first photo in the collection.

```rb
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
 
 "authenticity_token"=>"ek3R5OX0B0MFV7/ae88rLK4EqMbvQIpltMyBBmjsNlDONRFzLDMVeHdtrZ9wljQ/px7XPSP/9JdMWCg4M1OXLw==", 
"simple_product"=>{
  "vendor_id"=>"2", 
  "name"=>"The Regency Tea-Tray", 
  "vendor_code"=>"1105-082", 
  "photos_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{"sort_order"=>"0", "caption"=>"", "_destroy"=>"true", "id"=>"40"}, 
    "1"=>{"sort_order"=>"1", "caption"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"4639"}, 
    "2"=>{"sort_order"=>"2", "caption"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "id"=>"4640"}}, 
   }}, "commit"=>"Update Simple product", "id"=>"33"}
```

I'm a little stumped as to what in the logic is causing the true value to be set as a key. The code is very much boiler plate update action.

Comment: Please add your model code and any stack trace from the console for the error (not just the error itself)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Not quite sure what caused the change but it was actually a misconfigured `counter_cache`.

I am still not sure how this was setting the model attributes like it would, but after removing

`has_many :photos, counter_cache: true`

The error resolved.